# Get sum of time column in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUwxR.png]

What I tried is:

```
select  cast(sum(datediff(second,0,totalhr))/3600 as varchar(12)) + ':' + 
    right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,totalhr))/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) +
    ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,totalhr))%60 as varchar(2)),2) as total
    FROM   checkinout  where  YEAR(date)=2019 and  MONTH(date)=09 and userid=5
```

It giving wrong output 112:53:04 the right answer should be  116:30:04

Comment: What is the data type of your `totalhr` column?

Comment: This sounds like a floating point error. I would avoid using integers and use floating points instead e.g. `3600.0`.

Comment: time(0) @Zhorov

Answer (score 1):

If the `totalhr` column type is time and the format is `hh:mm:ss`,

For SQL Server: [DATEADD (datepart , number , date )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT DATEADD (ms, SUM (DATEDIFF (ms, '00:00:00.000', totalhr)), '00:00:00.000') AS total
FROM checkinout
WHERE
YEAR(date) = 2019 AND
MONTH(date) = 9 AND
userid = 5;
```

This function adds a specified number value (as a signed integer) to a specified datepart of an input date value, and then returns that modified value.

the above condition will return the calculated Date and Time but if you want just the hh:mm:ss in two digit format you can use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(hrs, '0#') + ':' + FORMAT(mins, '0#') + ':' +  FORMAT(secs, '0#') as total FROM
(SELECT hrs + (((((mins * 60) + (secs - (secs % 60))) / 60) - ((((mins * 60) + (secs - (secs % 60))) / 60) % 60)) / 60) AS hrs,
       (((mins * 60) + (secs - (secs % 60))) / 60) % 60 AS mins,
       secs % 60 AS secs
FROM (
SELECT SUM(116) AS hrs, // you have to replace the number with your column
       SUM(30) AS mins, // you have to replace the number with your column
       SUM(04) AS secs // you have to replace the number with your column
) AS dateSplit) AS total
```

Comment: this is giving wrong output 1900-01-05 16:53:04.000

Comment: @user143 Yes, because we only have 24hrs format you have to cast it.

Comment: Yes but I don't no how to cast i am new to this please help

Comment: @user143 you can use this as example SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE());

Comment: Please can you give example for this SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE());

Answer (score 0):

try running below query

```
 SELECT cast(sum(DATEPART(HOUR,totalhr)) as varchar(max)) + ':' + 
    cast(sum(DATEPART(MINUTE,totalhr)) as varchar(max)) + ':' + 
    cast(sum(DATEPART(SECOND,totalhr)) as varchar(max)) FROM checkinout
```

Comment: this is giving wrong output 107:347:364 correct  output should be 116:30:04

Comment: you need to write some logic to convert the total minutes and seconds to add it to the hour part..

Comment: You might get additional responses if you tagged it correctly. PLSQL is Oracle only, not Sql Server. Try T-Sql.